about python script executed in /var/www/html and permision
I have and php code which execute a python script and this works great!!
I change the owner of this script to www-data and give permission, also I included www-data in the sudoers to execute this script.
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/image.py
I'm trying to debug this python script in VScode but keep throwing:
Exception has occurred: PermissionError
I don't understand why vscode can't execute this script.
VSCode thorws error on this peaces of code:
im.save(/var/www/html/image_2024-11-21 08:51:39.635203.png)
im=Image.open('/var/www/html/image_2024-11-21 08:51:39.635203.png')

I can't open the image with python, it won't open debugging. But the images are generated using php.
Why I can't debug this python script with vscode?
I tried changing the owner of the script to my user, also give permission 777 to the script and images. I allow www-data to run this script from sudoers.
Regards
Gastón

www-data must not have sudo rights, this a major security breach. please read this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/is-it-safe-to-allow-www-data-to-execute-privileged-commands

are you in the group www-data?

Hi Folen, thanks for ur reply, yes I already add my user to the www-data but vscode is no able to execute the script. Only by changing the owner of the files Im able to use vscode to execute the script. If I do this then the php is no able to execute the python script.

Did you run vscode with root privileges?
